# Views vs Materialize Vs Materialized View in Kusto

Tags: .net, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

Scenario:
Data in kusto table is updated after 5 hours.
Task: Call query from .net API
In query , create a subquery and use that subquery to perform join on a bigger table

```
let table1=materialize(
Customer|where CustomerId=="cust-reg-aabb-cc232"|distinct CustomerId,City);
CustomerPurchase
|where CustomerId=="cust-reg-aabb-cc232"
//perform join with table1 and other things
```

or

```
let table1=view(){
Customer|where CustomerId=="cust-reg-aabb-cc232"|distinct CustomerId,City};
CustomerPurchase
|where CustomerId=="cust-reg-aabb-cc232"
//perform join with table1 and CustomerPurchase
```

CustomerPurchase and Customer data is being updated after every 5 hours(new rows being added). What is more optimized : create a view or use the [materialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/materializefunction) method.
I went through the documentation but could not understand the different between both.

Also since I am implementing an API, is it possible to use [materialized view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-overview) instead of table1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is quite clear:

[materialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/materializefunction)

> Allows caching a subquery result during the time of query execution in
> a way that other subqueries can reference the partial result.

[views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/schema-entities/views#the-view-keyword)

> Views are virtual tables based on the result-set of a Kusto Query
> Language query. Just like a real table, a view contains rows and
> columns. Unlike a real table, a view doesn't hold its own data
> storage.
>
> Views are defined through user-defined functions with the following
> requirements:
>
> - The result of the function must be tabular (for example, it cannot be    a scalar value).
> - The function must take no arguments.

The [view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/schema-entities/views#the-view-keyword) keyword

> By default, operators that support a wildcard syntax to specify table
> names will not reference views, even if the view's name matches the
> wildcard. An example of this type of operator is the union operator.
> In this case, use the view keyword to have the view included as well.

[Materialized views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-overview)

> Materialized views expose an aggregation query over a source table, or
> over another materialized view.

As the name suggests, the aggregation results are materialized, meaning - stored.
The results are being updated constantly, while the data keeps being ingested.

---

In your case, there seems to be no reason to use `materialize()`, nor the `view` keyword.

A materialized view such as the following (with filter on CustomerId) might improve performance when used instead of `table1`.

```
.create materialized-view Customer_mv on table Customer
{
    Customer
    | summarize by CustomerId, City
}
```

---

#### Update

Here are couple of examples that demonstrate the benefits of **materialize()**

#### 1.

```
let t = print x = rand(1000);
union t, t, t
```

| x |
| --- |
| 337 |
| 998 |
| 242 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8tJLVEoUbBVKCjKzCtRqACyihLzUjQMDQwMNK15uUrzMvPzFEp0wAgACmPsbiwAAAA=)

##### vs.

```
let t = materialize(print x = rand(1000));
union t, t, t
```

| x |
| --- |
| 722 |
| 722 |
| 722 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8tJLVEoUbBVyE0sSS3KTMzJrErVKCjKzCtRqACKFiXmpWgYGhgYaGpa83KV5mXm5ymU6IARADnzcw45AAAA)

#### 2.

```
let t1 = range i from 1 to 100000000 step 1 | summarize count() by i =  i%2;
let t2 = t1;
t1
| join kind=inner t2 on i
```

| i | count_ | i1 | count_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50000000 | 1 | 50000000 |
| 0 | 50000000 | 0 | 50000000 |

Execution Time: 4.4375515

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAAy2MsQ6DMAxEdyT%204ZZKsNWsVT4mUFO5JTYKZgDl4wlSb3v3dLewwwkBOeqHIZizJRDcQM9/sDmvtSvY9pRilpMx2a7e9RiPugmAPIZX2yz321DZqZJT2xR8TRQ/0XcQVc63N4VcXphX1nkAAAA=)

##### vs.

```
let t1 = materialize(range i from 1 to 100000000 step 1 | summarize count() by i =  i%2);
let t2 = t1;
t1
| join kind=inner t2 on i
```

| i | count_ | i1 | count_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50000000 | 1 | 50000000 |
| 0 | 50000000 | 0 | 50000000 |

Execution Time: 2.5313002

---

Here is an example that demonstrates the benefits of a view

```
.create-or-alter function StormEvents_top_5_deaths_v ()
{
    cluster("help").database("Samples").StormEvents
    |   project  Duration       = EndTime - StartTime
                ,Distance       = round(geo_distance_2points(BeginLon, BeginLat, EndLon, EndLat))
                ,TotalDeath     = DeathsDirect + DeathsIndirect
                ,TotalInjuries  = InjuriesIndirect + InjuriesIndirect
                ,TotalDamage    = DamageCrops + DamageProperty            
    |   where    TotalDeath > 0
    |   top 5 by TotalDeath
}
```

---

```
StormEvents_top_5_deaths_v
```

| Duration | Distance | TotalDeath | TotalInjuries | TotalDamage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20.07:00:00 | 0 | 14 | 0 | 0 |
| 00:18:00 | 20609 | 13 | 0 | 46000000 |
| 01:02:00 | 26080 | 11 | 0 | 250000000 |
| 2.20:00:00 | 0 | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| 18.09:00:00 | 0 | 10 | 0 | 0 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAAy2MzQ6CQAyE7yS8w1xI4Ga5mn2YVasp7nZNKQcJD29JnNt881PY4YSEmp1NcpGdR8v6Ygie1ioI3kCXv7A6f4IdWLdas0Ud97apjxNu39gkQIZ5uvZdOa/nAE7hnPruwNJE8RZ9JFFlO/OmkB/B/aynhgAAAA==)

Comment: I am not allowed to create new tables or something  in the kusto cluster . Between views and materialize(), which would be a better choice?

Comment: Also in case of views also we must be storing them somewhere, while in materialize() we store it in cache. So I think materialize() would be faster?

Comment: "Between views and materialize()" - Neither. Your code does not seem to have anything to benefit from using any of them.

Comment: "in case of views also we must be storing them somewhere" - No. We store the code, not the results.

Comment: I still don't see the benefit of using a view. What is the benefit in the example you show?

Comment: Which one specifically?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz The last one is the one that shows benefits of using a view. Just trying to understand why use view over a subquery. Should I just post another question and let you answer that?

Comment: I think I get it. Views allow user-defined functions. Is that all?

Comment: KQL UDF without parameters, is the equivalent for RDBMS view. There is no KQL object of type view (there is materialize view though)